# How to test if current browser supports a given tagName

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make a function to the effect of:

```
function supportsElem(tagName) {
   // returns boolean
}
```

where:

```
supportsElem("div") // true 
supportsElem("randomtext") // false
```

What the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Most browsers, even IE6, are willing to deal with made-up tags.  What is the larger purpose here? Are you trying to make your own HTML5 shim or something?

Comment: @Pointy I need to be able to discern a string like `div ! contenteditable` vs. `contenteditable ! checked` where the first part of the string might be a tagName. The rest of the parts are attr names. (I know I could use regex for all the tag names, but there like 108 of them so I was looking for a faster way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, cause i've never had to care about this.  But it'd seem to me you could create the element and then check to make sure it acts like it should.  For example, that it has certain properties, or that its constructor is right (or at least, isn't the same as a generic unsupported element would have).

An example of the constructor check (untested):

```
// pick a name that'll never be an element 
var generic_element = document.createElement('randomtext');

var tagName_to_check = document.createElement('div');
if (tagName_to_check.constructor === generic_element.constructor) {
    // the browser treats the node as a generic element, rather than
    // (eg) a DivElement
    // so it's probably unsupported
}
```

Comment: This method definitely works (even in IE8). See: http://jsfiddle.net/t9T5A/5/ Nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function testTag(tagname) {
    return document.createElement(tagname) instanceof HTMLUnknownElement;
}
```

I don't know what kind of browser support this (`HTMLUnknownElement`) will have though.

Comment: Good idea. That seems to work in standards compliant browsers. It doesn't work in IE8 though. Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/p68AP/1/

Comment: In IE8 the equivalent is `HTMLGenericElement` Try: http://jsfiddle.net/MX4Vp/2/ in IE

Answer (score 1):

This is more effort than it's worth.

Just keep a dictionary of all the valid tags ([easy to find online](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_html_dtd.asp)). Basically an array of strings

then its just

```
var dictionary = ["div", "a", "input", "span", ..., "td"];
var myTag = "div";
dictionary.indexOf(myTag); // if this doesn't return -1, then the tag is valid
```

Comment: Right, but that just assumes support, which was actually my original idea, except I think a regex would be faster than the array. FYI the most reliable list of elems is at http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/elements.html or 
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/index.html and you should probably also read http://w3fools.com/ ;)

Comment: Assumes support of what? indexOf will be faster than a regec. Also I know w3schools is rubbish, it was just the first search result.

Comment: I meant testing if the browser actually does recognize the element, vs. testing if the browser should recognize the element.

Comment: and the regex is definitely faster, especially when you group the common letters. See: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-indexof-tag-list

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create the element, then test it against a method specific to this element.

Comment: Right but I don't know what the tag is. Is there a method specific to all known elements but not the maed up ones?